# React change iframe src with user input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I want to be able to change an an `iframe`'s `src` with the help of React but I don't know where to start.

I managed to build what I want with html and JavaScript, but it is not working when I dump the code in a react project.

Please see how the code I've tried works, below, and point me in the right direction please.

```html
<input type="number" id="book"></input>
<input type="number" id="page"></input>
<button type="button" onClick="goBook();">Submit</button>
<iframe
    id="myBook"
    src="https://www.google.com"
    height="720"
    width="1280"
    frameborder="0"
    scrolling="no"
    allowfullscreen="true">
</iframe>

<script>
    function goBook(){
  document.getElementById("myBook").src = "https://www.example.com/b="+document.getElementById("book").value+"&p="+document.getElementById("page").value;
}
</script>
```

**Edit:** I tried converting html and js files to jsx with an online convertor but it did not help.

Comment: I think you need to create a form in react. you can use useRef hook to point a reference to the iframe element. And on click of submit button you can take action

Comment: @AyusMohanty your implementation is exactly what i needed. I tried adding your code to my project and got the following error...                                                                                 Line 13:19:  'useRef' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 14:19:  'useRef' is not defined      no-undef
  Line 15:21:  'useRef' is not defined      no-undef

Comment: Are you importing useRef()? `import { useRef, useState } from "react";`

Comment: And are you using functional components?

Comment: @AyusMohanty yes and yes... Your code works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
import { useRef, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const googleUrl = "https://www.google.com";

  const refBook = useRef(null);
  const refPage = useRef(null);
  const refIframe = useRef(null);
  const [iframSrc, setIframeUrl] = useState(googleUrl);

  const goBook = () => {
    setIframeUrl(
      `${googleUrl}/b=${refBook.current.value}&p=${refPage.current.value}`
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input type="number" ref={refBook}></input>
      <input type="number" ref={refPage}></input>
      <button type="button" onClick={goBook}>
        Submit
      </button>
      <iframe
        title="myBook"
        src={iframSrc}
        height="720"
        width="1280"
        frameBorder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        allowFullScreen={true}
        ref={refIframe}
      ></iframe>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And here is my implementation for your problem in a coding sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/iframe-src-change-s2yrh

Comment: Interesting solution. Important stuff from [the docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useRef): "_By using a ref, you ensure that:
**1.** You can store information between re-renders (unlike regular variables, which reset on every render).
**2.** Changing it does not trigger a re-render (unlike state variables, which trigger a re-render).
**3.** The information is local to each copy of your component (unlike the variables outside, which are shared)._"

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with create-react-app.

After you get the basic react application template, Go to App.js and write this code:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [srcURL, setsrcURL] = useState("https://www.google.com");
  const [book, setBook] = useState(null);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(null);

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (book && page) {
      setsrcURL(`${"https://www.google.com"}/b=${book}&p=${page}`);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="number"
        name="book"
        placeholder="Book Number"
        onChange={(e) => setBook(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        type="number"
        placeholder="Page Number"
        name="page"
        onChange={(e) => setPage(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={handleSubmit}>
        Submit
      </button>
      <iframe
        name="myBook"
        src={srcURL}
        height="720"
        width="1280"
        frameBorder="0"
        scrolling="no"
        allowFullScreen={true}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```